# Wrong duration info while Merging two wav files in c++

Tags: c++, file, audio, media, wav

Im trying to merge two wav file in c++. What i am doing is I'm opening the two wav files as binary ifstream and also creating a new ofstream output wavfile.

```
ifstream wavFileA("fileA.wav",ios::binary) ;      
ifstream wavFileB("fileB.wav",ios::binary);      
ofstream wavoutputfile("output.wav",ios::binary);
```

then i copied the whole wavfileA along with its headers into the output file and then i copied the wavfileB omitting the first 44bits(ie header info of wavfileB).

```
wavFileA.seekg(0,ios::end);
int leng2 = wavFileA.tellg();
cout << leng2 << endl;
wavFileA.seekg(0,ios::beg);
int pos;
pos = wavoutputfile.tellp();
cout << pos << endl << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < leng2 ; i++)                 
{
    byteB = readByte(wavFileA);
    wavoutputfile << byteB;
}

pos = wavoutputfile.tellp();
cout <<"current pos-"<< pos << endl << endl;

wavoutputfile.seekp(pos, ios::beg);

wavFileB.seekg(0,ios::end);
int leng3 = wavFileB.tellg();
wavFileB.seekg(44,ios::beg);
cout<<"length --"<<leng3<<endl;
for(int i= 0 ; i < leng3-44 ; i++)
{
    byteC = readByte(wavFileB);                   
    wavoutputfile << byteC;
}
pos = wavoutputfile.tellp();
cout <<"end pos--"<< pos << endl << endl;
```

Next i modified the header information in the output wav file and changed the ChunkSize in the header into the (size of my ouput file minus(-) 4bytes) (ie size of RIFF) and then i changed the Subchunk2Size in headers to (my whole filesize minus(-) size of header).

```
int fsize = pos-8;

unsigned char bArray[4];


wavoutputfile.seekp(4, ios::beg);

bArray[0] = ((fsize >> 24) & 0xFF);
bArray[1] = ((fsize >> 16) & 0xFF);
bArray[2] = ((fsize >> 8) & 0xFF);
bArray[3] = ((fsize) & 0xFF);

for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
{
    wavoutputfile << bArray[i];
}

int dataSize = (pos-44);

wavoutputfile.seekp(42, ios::beg);

bArray[0] = ((dataSize >> 24) & 0xFF);
bArray[1] = ((dataSize >> 16) & 0xFF);
bArray[2] = ((dataSize >> 8) & 0xFF);
bArray[3] = ((dataSize) & 0xFF);

for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
{
    wavoutputfile << bArray[i];
}

wavoutputfile.seekp(0, ios::end);
wavFileA.close();
wavFileB.close();

wavoutputfile.close();
```

This code merges the files successfully and it plays the file also properly but the duration of the files shows a wrong value which is much bigger than the actual duration. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Constantin. But i found out where i was going wrong.

I forgot to consider that ChunkSize and SubChunkSize2 were ordered in little endian systems.
so i changed the part where i was entering those information in the headers and the whole thing started working.

```
for (int i=3; i>=0 ; i--)  //I made the change here
{
    outputWavFile << bArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Next i modified the header information in the output wav file and
>   changed the ChunkSize in the header into the (size of my ouput file
>   minus(-) 4bytes) (ie size of RIFF)

That's probably your main problem: You should subtract the filesize by 8 bytes (not 4 bytes) in order to get the ChunkSize. Also make sure that Subchunk2Size is really the size of your raw audio data without the header - don't use a magic number like `pos - 44`, it makes your code hard to read and to understand. Better calculate it with your sample count, number of channels and bits per sample. i.e.

```
Subchunk2Size = sampleCount * channelCount * bitDepth/8;
```

If all that doesn't help, please show us the header (around first 72 bytes) of your saved wavefile (in hex) together with the expected length.